# Dynamic web twain version 10.0

Tags: image, dynamic, save, twain, scanning

if i run my code in mozilla firefox after i click scan in UI select source window is opened and then it crashed. 
bt the same code if i run on chrome it scan the image in the scanner after that if i click the scan on the new window it scan properly and crashed during file transfer and chrome tell a error message "a plugin (shockwave flash) isnt responding "

what may be the prob

```
function onScan(no_of_pages)
        {
            if (DWObject)
            {
                if (DWObject.SourceCount > 0)
                {
                    DWObject.SelectSource();
                    DWObject.IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire = true;
                    DWObject.AcquireImage();
                    DWObject.MaxImagesInBuffer = no_of_pages;
                }
                else
                    alert("No TWAIN compatible drivers detected.");
            }
        }

        function Dynamsoft_ChangeConfig(config){
            config.onPrintMsg = g_DWT_PrintMsg;
        }

        function g_DWT_PrintMsg(strMessage) {
            alert(strMessage);
        }
function OnPostTransferCallback()
        {
            try{
                if(DWObject.MaxImagesInBuffer == DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer)
                {
                    DWObject.CloseSource();
                    sendToFlash() ;
                }else
                {
                    //TBD
                }
            }catch(err){
                alert(err.message);
            }

        }

        //Call back function from the

        function sendToFlash()
        {
            try{

                var flashMovie = window.document.flashContent;
                flashMovie.sendToActionScript(DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer);
                //document.getElementById("ICANSWF").sendToActionScript();
            }catch(err){

                alert(err.message);
            }
        }

        //call from flash for uploading documents

        function onUpload(serialNo)
        {
            //alert("upload the file");
            var imageArr = new Array();
            try{
                var imageName;
                var uploadPage;
                var serverHost;
                var CurrentPathName = unescape(location.pathname);  // get current PathName in plain ASCII
                var CurrentPath = CurrentPathName.substring(0, CurrentPathName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                uploadPage = CurrentPath+"TempUpload.php";
                //uploadPage = CurrentPath+"UploadDocument.php";
                //serverHost = "blabla";
                //window.Plugin.HTTPPort =1451;
                serverHost = "our host";
                DWObject.HTTPPort = 80;
                DWObject.IfSSL = false;
                //alert(Plugin.HowManyImagesInBuffer);
                for(var i=0;i < DWObject.HowManyImagesInBuffer;i++)
                {
                    imageName = serialNo+"_"+(i+1)+".png";
                    DWObject.HTTPUploadThroughPost(serverHost,i,uploadPage,imageName);

                    if (DWObject.ErrorCode == 0)
                    {
                        //alert(imageName);
                        imageArr.push({"label":imageName,"source":"http://"+serverHost+":"+DWObject.HTTPPort+"/icanindonesia/AppData/Temp/"+imageName}); //Push image name and location in an array

                    }
                    else //succeded
                    {

                        alert(DWObject.ErrorString);
                        //imageArr[i] = imageName;
                        //alert(imageArr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }catch(err){
                //alert("onUpload");
                alert(err.message);
            }

            console.log(imageArr);
            return imageArr;
        }

        function startDownload(url)
        {
            //var url='.zip';
            window.open(url,'Download');
        }

        function openDocument(url){
            window.open(url, '_blank',"ican image viewer");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@priya, this is Rachel from Dynamsoft.Thanks for using our Dynamic Web TWAIN SDK. Which version of Firefox and Chrome are you using? We now also have newer version of Dynamic Web TWAIN which you may try. Please [contact our support team](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Company/Contact.aspx) to get better help.